# Chess Pawn Puzzle

Tags: chess

[image]

What is the least required number moves to be played to arrive on the position shown above ? Note: no illegal moves.

Comment: That's insane. I swore there was no legal way to do that.

Comment: Thought it would be easy...until I saw that the pawns are on opposite sides of the board (Black on white side and vise versa)

Comment: Here the black and white squares should be swopped, or there will be no legal way to do it since pawns only move forward(without capturing)

Comment: Disclaimer: the above question was similar to post of Ariana @ Chess Stack exchange almost 2years ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that

> we see the board from *Black's* position – otherwise, it's not possible as for the pawns to pass each other, they'll need to capture something and all pieces are still on the board.

the answer is

> [40 moves](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/14777/7297) as 'predicted' by Chess Stack Exchange user @chackerian. You'll need 8 moves (by each side) for the pawns (black and white); 10 moves for the rooks (they cannot jump over the pawns, they need to move around them); 7 moves for the kings; 3 moves for the queens (who again cannot jump over the pawns); 8 moves for the knights and 4 moves for the bishops.

The position can be reached [as follows](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/14772/7297):

> 1. a4 {First, we need to get the rooks in position. They'll be hard to swap once the board is full.} a5 2. h4 h5 3. Rh3 Rh6 4. Rg3 Rf6 5. Rg6 Rf3 6. Rh6 Rh3 7. Ra3 Ra6 8. Rc3 Rb6 9. Rcc6 Rbb3 10. Ra6 Ra3 {Now, we can start with the knights. They're tricky because they need to swap places via the four center squares. Note that we cannot move the center pawns *before* the knights.} 11. Nf3 Nc6 12. Ne5 Nd4 13. Nc6 Nf6 14. Nc3 Nd5 15. Ne4 Nc3 {It's time for the kings to come out of their hiding, but they have do this carefully because of the knights.} 16. Rh8 d5 17. Ra8 Kd7 18. Nf6+ Kd6 19. e4 Ra1 20. Ba6 b5 21. Nb8 Kc5 {The black monarch chooses queenside - that means his colleague has to take the other one.} 22. Ng8 Nde2 23. d4+ Kc4 24. Kd2 Rh1 25. Ke3 Ng1 26. Kf4 Bh3 27. g4 f5 28. Kg5 e5+ 29. Kg6 Bf1 30. Bh6 {Note how the c1-h6 and a3-f8 diagonals have been left open for the transfer of the last four pieces.} Qg5+ 31. Kf7 Ba3 32. Ke8 Qc1 33. Qd2 Nb1 34. Qg5 {OK, we're almost there now, from here it's a walk in the park.} Qd1 35. b4 Kc3 36. Qd8 g5 37. Bf8 c5 38. Bc8 Kd2 39. c4 Bc1 40. f4 Ke1 {And we're done!}

The link contains a 'replayer' for easy viewing of the solution (press 'Flip' to view it as black).

Comment: Your solution does not reach the wanted position.

Comment: @xehpuk Yes it does. You're probably looking at the board upside down. Try the "Flip" button.

Comment: @xehpuk is probably right, the queen and king are switched. I'm inclined to consider this a flaw in the puzzle rather than the solution; after all, it makes more sense for the kings to exchange positions rather than the white king with the black queen and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not in the position to adjust the solution right now, but I'm pretty sure it's moderately easy.

Comment: @ Glorfindel-I tried to look for duplication in puzzling chess tag since I thought it is probably posted before but found none.Thanks for the link